# How to add validation for date with format mm/dd/yyyy inside model rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, model

How can I add validation for a date with format mm/dd/yyyy inside model rails 4 ?

So, I only want a date with the format mm/dd/yyyy created inside model.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
validates_format_of :date_of_birth, :with => /\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}/, :message => "^Date must be in the following format: mm/dd/yyyy"
```

[Here](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/11506)'s another approach.

Comment: thak you @Emu fix my problem

Comment: This is accepting  any string containing valid formatted string eg. 11/12/20162017. Valid format is /\A\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}\Z/.